# Quark-antiquark plasma and Fermi-Dirac statistics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, quarks

I'm attempting to work my way through the following set of question:

> a) A plasma consists of an equilibrium mixture at temperature $T$ of quarks, $q$, (massless,relativistic,  spin $\frac{1}{2}$,  particles) with chemical potential $\mu(T)$ and antiquarks, $\tilde{q}$ (massless, relativistic, spin $\frac{1}{2}$ particles) with chemical potential $-\mu(T)$. Prove that the total energy of the system $E = E_{q} + E_{\tilde{q}}$ is given by:
>   $$E = \frac{2\pi V}{h^{3}c^{3}}[\frac{7\pi^{4}}{15}(kT)^{4}+2\pi^{2}(kT)^{2}\mu^{2}+\mu^{4}].$$
>
> b) and the baryon number $N_b = \frac{1}{3}(N_q-N_\tilde{q})$ is given by:
>   $$N_b = \frac{8\pi V}{9h^{3}c^{3}}[\pi^{2}(kT)^{2}\mu + \mu^{3}].$$

I'm familiar with 
[Fermi-Dirac statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics#Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_distribution)
,
 however, applying it to this problem seems to be beyond my capabilities. I've been trying for 3 days to calculate the total energy of the particles so any ideas would be very welcome.

In regards to parts b), I know quarks/antiquarks have a baryon number of $\frac{1}{3}$ & $-\frac{1}{3}$, but that is about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need the standard, but not obvious, integrals
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d\epsilon}{2\pi}\frac 1{2!}\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2\pi}\right)^2\left\{ \frac{1}{1+e^{\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}}-\theta(-\epsilon)\right\} =\frac{1}{3!}\left(\frac{\mu}{2\pi}\right)^3+\left(\frac{\mu}{2\pi}\right)\frac{T^2}{4!}\\
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d\epsilon}{2\pi}\frac1{3!}\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2\pi}\right)^3\left\{ \frac{1}{1+e^{\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}}-\theta(-\epsilon)\right\} =\frac{1}{4!}\left(\frac{\mu}{2\pi}\right)^4+\frac{1}{2!}\left(\frac{\mu}{2\pi}\right)^2\frac{T^2}{4!}+\frac 78\frac{T^4}{6!}.
$$
You do not need separate integrals for the quark and antiquarks. The antiquarks are just holes in the negative energy Dirac sea of quarks.

So, for example, in part (b) we are asked to evaluate the integral 
$$
n_q-n_{\bar q}= \int\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3} \left\{ \frac{1}{1+e^{\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}}- \frac{1}{1+e^{\beta(\epsilon+\mu)}}\right\}.
$$

Remembering that  $\epsilon=\pm |k|$, we proceed as follows: 
$$
n_q-n_{\bar q}= \int\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3} \left\{ \frac{1}{1+e^{\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}}- \frac{1}{1+e^{\beta(\epsilon+\mu)}}\right\}\\
= \int_0^\infty \frac{4\pi \epsilon^2 d\epsilon }{(2\pi)^3} \left\{ \frac{1}{1+e^{\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}}- \frac{1}{1+e^{\beta(\epsilon+\mu)}}\right\}
\\
= \int_{0}^\infty \frac{4\pi \epsilon^2 d\epsilon}{(2\pi)^3} \left\{\frac{1}{1+e^{\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}}
+\frac{e^{\beta(\epsilon+\mu)}}{1+e^{\beta(\epsilon+\mu)}}- \frac{1+e^{\beta(\epsilon+\mu)}}{1+e^{\beta(\epsilon+\mu)}} \right\}\\
=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{4\pi \epsilon^2 d\epsilon}{(2\pi)^3} \left\{\frac{1}{1+e^{\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}}
+\frac{1}{1+e^{\beta(-\epsilon-\mu)}}- 1 \right\}\\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {4\pi \epsilon^2 d\epsilon}{(2\pi)^3} \left\{ 
\frac{1}{1+e^{\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}}
- \theta(-\epsilon) \right\}.
$$
The last line can be evaluated via my standard integral. (Remember there should be an aditional factor of two for "spin".) The step function can be thought of as  subtraction of the unwanted contribution of the filled Dirac sea.

The standard integrals come from a generating function $$
I(\tau)\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\int_0^\infty \frac{d\epsilon}{2\pi} \left\{\frac{e^{\tau\epsilon/2\pi}}{1+e^{\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}}+\frac{e^{-\tau\epsilon/2\pi}}{1+e^{\beta(-\epsilon-\mu)}}-
e^{-\tau\epsilon/2\pi}\right\}\\
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d\epsilon}{2\pi} \left\{\frac{e^{\tau\epsilon/2\pi}}{1+e^{\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}}\right\}-\frac 1\tau\nonumber\\
= e^{\mu\tau/2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d\epsilon}{2\pi} \left\{\frac{e^{\tau(\epsilon-\mu)/2\pi}}{1+e^{\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}}\right\}-\frac 1\tau\\
=  e^{\mu\tau/2\pi} T\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d\xi }{2\pi} \left\{\frac{e^{\xi T\tau/2\pi}}{1+e^\xi}\right\}-\frac 1\tau\nonumber\\
= e^{\mu\tau/2\pi} T  \int_{0}^\infty \frac{dx }{2\pi}\frac{x^{T\tau/2\pi-1}}{1+x} -\frac 1\tau\\
=  \frac 1{\tau}\left\{ \frac{(\frac{\tau T}{2})}{\sin(\frac{\tau T}{2})} e^{\tau\mu/2\pi}-1\right\}.
$$
We have set $x=\exp\{\beta(\epsilon-\mu)\}$ and at the last step we have used the branch cut integral
$$
\int_0^\infty dx \frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{1+x}= \frac{\pi}{\sin\pi \alpha}, \quad 0<\alpha<1.
$$
Expanding in powers of  $\tau$ and comparing coefficients on LHS and RHS gives us the standard integrals.

Comment: How does this give me energy?

Comment: Plug and chug:  the first integral is the one appropriate for the Baryon number, and the second with the extra $\epsilon$ gives you the energy, Just remember that the momentum density of states is $d^3k/(2\pi)^3 = 4 \pi \epsilon^2 d\epsilon/(2\pi)^3$.  The negative $\epsilon part in the antiquark contrbution.

Comment: So what exactly do I plug these integrals into? At this point, I'm completely bamboozled by this problem.

Comment: I modify answer to give a hint.